# in solution of diamond problem, why we need to inherit grand parent class two time virtually?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

In the code below, why do I have to inherit class `A` virtually in both classes `B` and `C`?

I have learned that first compiler finds targeted function in derived class. If it is not found in it, then compiler has to search in its base classes. So, if I virtually inherit only once (class `A`) then compiler should find targeted function (`aa()`) through only one path, i.e. `D` to `C` to `A` in below case.

If I inherit it only once then problem still remains.

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;


class A
{
public: 
    void aa() { cout<<"aa"<<endl; } 
};

class B: public virtual A
{  };

class C: public /*virtual*/ A
{  };

class D: public C,public B
{  };

int main()
{
    D d1;
    d1.aa();
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error : Member is ambiguous: 'A::aa' and 'A::aa' in function `main()`
```

Comment: Why did you believe it would work? Can you spell out your intuition?

Comment: _... compiler have to search in it's **all** base classes_  I emphasized **all** because it means **all** base classes.  And that's when the compiler finds two matches.

Comment: @dr-gut I merged your edit (grammatical fixes) after I edited it (my edit was grammatically inferior)

Comment: There are actually two inheritance paths: D-C-A and D-B-A so two instances of A and two sets of instance members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer would be: just because. It's the rule. You have too. Period.

If you want another rule, make up another language. Just try to do that if you dislike a rule in any programming language and get back to us, tell us what exact semantics you came up with.

But a deeper answer is that it would make very little sense for virtual to contaminate non virtual stuff.

Do you expect a non virtual member function to become virtual because some other function with the same signature is virtual in some other class, and they end up being two bases? This is a real question, in an imaginary language you would make up to fit your intuition:

```
struct A {
   void f(); // non virtual!
};

struct AA : A {
   void f(); // non virtual, hides, does not override
};

struct B {
   virtual void f();
};

struct BB : B {
   void f(); // virtual overrider 
};

struct A {
   void f(); // non virtual!
};

struct AABB : AA, BB {
   // is AA::f() now virtual? what about A::f()?
};
```

If you don't expect virtualness in `BB` to alter the semantics of `AA`, then you have the general answer: writing virtual does not change the virtualness of any previously established virtualness.

So all you have to accept is that virtualness is a property of inheritance, a one-to-one relation, between a derived class and its base. Inheritance is established as virtual or non virtual in any given class.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how it works. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class):

> **Virtual base classes**
>
> For each distinct base class that is specified virtual, the most
>   derived object contains only one base class subobject of that type,
>   even if the class appears many times in the inheritance hierarchy (**as
>   long as it is inherited virtual every time**).

Maybe your understanding is that "once inherited virtual the base class appears only once as subobject", however the more correct informal way would be "all virtual inherited subobjects appear as only a single subobject".

Consider the contrived situation where a `baseA` wants its `base` to appear in the final derived class. It would use non-virtual inheritance:

```
struct baseA : base {};
```

Now a `baseB` class wants to have its derived contain a `base` subobject that is shared among all other virtual inherited base classes, it would use virtual inheritance:

```
struct baseB : virtual base {};
```

Now we can inherit from both:

```
struct foo : baseA, baseB {};
```

If virtual inheritance would work the way you expected, this would break `baseA` (it assumes `foo` gets a seperate `base` subobject). Also it would be counterintuitive, that adding a `baseB` inheritance would turn `baseA`s inheritance into a virtual one.

This is actually all just speculation and the TL;DR is really just: Thats how virtual inheritance works by definition.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good explanation in the included link.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance

You'll need to scroll down just past halfway to the section about "the dreaded diamond". The section immediately below that explains how to deal with the dreaded diamond -- through the use of the keyword "virtual".

In short, when you have multiple inheritance, and some of the things you inherit from share a common ancestor, you end up with two copies of the base object. In your example, you get two copies of A -- one in B and one in C. And then when using it from D, your code doesn't know which one you really mean. That's probably not what you really want. You only want a single instance of A, and you want B and C to share it.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your `virtual` keyword for class C, you have a second instance of A in your class tree. And if you have two times A in your class accessing a member is `ambiguous`!

If you extend your example like this, you can see both instances and get rid of the error message:

```
int instance_count = 0;
class A
{
    int myInstance;

    public:

    A(): myInstance{ instance_count++ } { std::cout << "create instance # " << myInstance << std::endl;}

    void aa() { std::cout<<"Instance"<< myInstance << std::endl; }
};

class B:public A
{  };
class C:public /*virtual*/ A
{  };
class D:public C,public B
{  };

int main()
{
    D d1;
    d1.::C::aa(); // you can access each instance by giving the path through the hirarchy
    d1.::B::aa();
    return 0;
}
```